# Application not finding a folder

Tags: java, jar, path, migration, liquibase

I have a Java application that uses Liquibase and I am having trouble finding some files.
In my main class I have this code to update my database

```
connection = openConnection(dbUrl,dbUsername,dbPassword);
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(changelog, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
logger.warn("LIQUIBASE:"+liquibase.toString());
liquibase.update(new Contexts("abc"));
```

And the value of the variable changelog is `classpath:/db/changelog/master/db.changelog-master.xml`. The changelog file is indeed found but the folder it points  to it's not.

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd" >

    <includeAll path="./../migrations/Test"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Since in my jar file the file changelog has the path `migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\db\changelog\master\db.changelog-master.xml` and the folder the path `migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\db\changelog\migrations\Test` shouldn't the path be correct?

Comment: Did you try to indicate the flag `relativeToChangelogFile=true` in the `includeAll` tag? Defining the full class path instead of a relative one should work properly as well.

Comment: @jccampanero will try that. When I used SpringApplication. Run it I did not have this problem

Comment: @jccampanero tried that but no success

Comment: I am sorry to hear that Fabio. Did it fail even with `<includeAll path="db/changelog/migrations/Test"/>`?

Comment: @jccampanero yes.,but for some reason include file works perfectly

Comment: @jccampanero Also is it possible to point for a file outside of my jar file?

Comment: You mean, including each file separately?

Comment: @jccampanero yes. For example `<include file="/db/changelog/migrations/Test/teste2.xml"></include>` works fine

Comment: That is very strange indeed. And, any errors are displayed? It may be a bug although honestly I use to include every file separately. What library version are you using?

Comment: @jccampanero no,that's why I only figured the issue when I tried to use include file